# How do you isolate variable "a" in this equation in PHP : log(20) = log(a) + 3b?

Tags: math

My highschool years are far behind and I'm having trouble remembering how to isolate the "a" variable in this equation :

ln(20) = ln(a) + 3 * b

b = 0.4605

From this website (last section, at the very bottom http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/expoapps_3.htm) : "Back-substituting b into either of the previous equations gives ln (a) = 4.377, and anti-logging gives a = 79.6"

I know this is fairly simple and I just need a quick help!

Thanks a lot for your time

Joel

Comment: b is negative. Makes all the difference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a programming question, but

```
log(20) = log(a) + 3
log(20) - log(a) = 3
log(20/a) = 3
20/a = 10^3
20/(10^3) = a
```

// EDIT

You're right, there was a mistake, it's fixed now.  Also, b = **-** 0.4605

Here's the original method, using *e* instead of *log*:

20/(e^(3*(-0.4605))) = 79.6173691

Comment: I think there is an error in the formula. The formula I'm refering to is in the section of this webpage : http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/expoapps_3.htm . The ln(20) = ln(a) + 3b.... where b = 0.4605 and a is supposed to be a = 4.377. Could you double check?

Comment: @Gumbo - Probable? There's no probably about it. The question was written with LOG.  Look at any math text and it will tell you a LOG with no base is assumed to be 10.

Comment: iirc log = base 10 and ln = base e

Comment: @Steve: The PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php) states that an unspecified base defaults the `log` function to base *e* (and the question is tagged PHP). The clarification given in the above comment uses `ln`, like the linked web page

Comment: oh I'm sorry about the confusion, the website said "ln" and I'm programming in PHP so I found the function "log" and this is what I posted here... I corrected the original post with what the real answer is, could someone complete?

Comment: @Steve: [PHP’s `log` function](http://php.net/log) calculates the natural logarithm if no other base is specified. And by the way, even if the base is 10 your derivation is wrong. It needs to be 10^3 and not 3^10.

Comment: @Gumbo, @Gareth - Fair enough then. But once again I'm not too impressed with the needle/haystack haystack/needle shenanigans in PHP.

Comment: @Gumbo again - Fastest gun in the west misfired. Fixed a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for you answers

Comment: ln is always base e.  I've seen log be base 10, base 2, and base e -- it's heavily context dependent.

Comment: @wnoise Annoying but true. Log being base 2 irks me especially as nobody uses that convention outside of CS.